# Is it possible to query an `R` function for the default value of its parameters?

Tags: r

In most cases, the default value of function parameters is given in the documentation. 
However, in some cases the default value is computed from other parameters (including the data itself), so it cannot possibly be specified in the documentation.

For example, how might I discover the default `lambda` grid used for the function `glmnet` in the library `glmnet`?
According to the documentation, the default `lambda` is computed based on `nlambda`, which defaults to `100`, and `lambda.min.ratio`, which appears to be a data-derived value.

When I run this function with a given data set, I would like to know the value of `lambda` that it used. This is particularly useful when using `cv.glmnet`, because I want to know which `lambda`'s it is picking among when I do not supply one.

Sample Input:

```
library(glmnet)

set.seed(1)
x=rnorm(100)
eps=rnorm(100)

y = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + eps

xmat=model.matrix(y~poly(x,10,raw=T),data=data.frame(x=x))

cv.out=cv.glmnet(xmat, y,alpha=0) # What is the lambda used here?
bestlam=cv.out$lambda.min
print(bestlam)


# When a grid is specified, the result is very different and sometimes worse.
grid=10^seq(10,-2,length=100)
cv.out=cv.glmnet(xmat, y,alpha=0, lambda=grid)
bestlam=cv.out$lambda.min
print(bestlam)
```

Sample Output (Notice they are very different):

```
0.3619167
0.04037017
```

Comment: You should be able to find it in the function itself. If typing `glmnet` doesn't return the function, you can try `getAnywhere('glmnet')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the default values depend on the value of the other arguments, then I see no other solution than enter the function in debug mode when it is called. You can use `debugonce` for example:

```
> debugonce(cv.glmnet)
> 
> cv.out=cv.glmnet(xmat, y,alpha=0) # What is the lambda used here?
debugging in: cv.glmnet(xmat, y, alpha = 0)
[...]
Browse[2]> ls()
#  [1] "foldid"       "grouped"      "keep"         "lambda"       "nfolds"       "offset"      
#  [7] "parallel"     "type.measure" "weights"      "x"            "y"           
Browse[2]> lambda
NULL
Browse[2]> c
>
```

So for that first call, `lambda` is `NULL`. However, if you repeat that approach for your second call to `cv.glmnet`, you will see that in that case `lambda` is a numeric vector of length 100.

Comment: I was not even aware that `R` had a debugger, but even less aware that you could enter library functions like this and see variables inside their environments +1 and accept!

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised neither of these was posted yet, but the obvious functions are `args` and `formals`:

`args` shows just the "top" of the function with no body, unlike calling `cv.glmnet`:

```
> args(cv.glmnet)
function (x, y, weights, offset = NULL, lambda = NULL, type.measure = c("mse", 
    "deviance", "class", "auc", "mae"), nfolds = 10, foldid, 
    grouped = TRUE, keep = FALSE, parallel = FALSE, ...) 
NULL
```

`formals` gives those arguments as a list:

```
> formals(cv.glmnet)
$x


$y


$weights


$offset
NULL

$lambda
NULL

$type.measure
c("mse", "deviance", "class", "auc", "mae")

$nfolds
[1] 10

$foldid


$grouped
[1] TRUE

$keep
[1] FALSE

$parallel
[1] FALSE

$...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just type the function name and hit enter to get the function's source code. In your given example, lambda is defaulting to NULL.

```
cv.glmnet
## function (x, y, weights, offset = NULL, lambda = NULL, type.measure = c("mse", 
##     "deviance", "class", "auc", "mae"), nfolds = 10, foldid, 
##     grouped = TRUE, keep = FALSE, parallel = FALSE, ...) 
## {
##     if (missing(type.measure)) 
##         type.measure = "default"
##     else type.measure = match.arg(type.measure)
##     if (!is.null(lambda) && length(lambda) < 2) 
##         stop("Need more than one value of lambda for cv.glmnet")
##     N = nrow(x)
##     if (missing(weights)) 
##         weights = rep(1, N)
##     else weights = as.double(weights)
##     y = drop(y)
##     glmnet.call = match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
##     which = match(c("type.measure", "nfolds", "foldid", "grouped", 
##         "keep"), names(glmnet.call), F)
##     if (any(which)) 
##         glmnet.call = glmnet.call[-which]
##     glmnet.call[[1]] = as.name("glmnet")
##     glmnet.object = glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, 
##         lambda = lambda, ...)
##     glmnet.object$call = glmnet.call
##     is.offset = glmnet.object$offset
##     lambda = glmnet.object$lambda
##     if (inherits(glmnet.object, "multnet")) {
##         nz = predict(glmnet.object, type = "nonzero")
##         nz = sapply(nz, function(x) sapply(x, length))
##         nz = ceiling(apply(nz, 1, median))
##     }
##     else nz = sapply(predict(glmnet.object, type = "nonzero"), 
##         length)
##     if (missing(foldid)) 
##         foldid = sample(rep(seq(nfolds), length = N))
##     else nfolds = max(foldid)
##     if (nfolds < 3) 
##         stop("nfolds must be bigger than 3; nfolds=10 recommended")
##     outlist = as.list(seq(nfolds))
##     if (parallel && require(foreach)) {
##         outlist = foreach(i = seq(nfolds), .packages = c("glmnet")) %dopar% 
##             {
##                 which = foldid == i
##                 if (is.matrix(y)) 
##                   y_sub = y[!which, ]
##                 else y_sub = y[!which]
##                 if (is.offset) 
##                   offset_sub = as.matrix(offset)[!which, ]
##                 else offset_sub = NULL
##                 glmnet(x[!which, , drop = FALSE], y_sub, lambda = lambda, 
##                   offset = offset_sub, weights = weights[!which], 
##                   ...)
##             }
##     }
##     else {
##         for (i in seq(nfolds)) {
##             which = foldid == i
##             if (is.matrix(y)) 
##                 y_sub = y[!which, ]
##             else y_sub = y[!which]
##             if (is.offset) 
##                 offset_sub = as.matrix(offset)[!which, ]
##             else offset_sub = NULL
##             outlist[[i]] = glmnet(x[!which, , drop = FALSE], 
##                 y_sub, lambda = lambda, offset = offset_sub, 
##                 weights = weights[!which], ...)
##         }
##     }
##     fun = paste("cv", class(glmnet.object)[[1]], sep = ".")
##     cvstuff = do.call(fun, list(outlist, lambda, x, y, weights, 
##         offset, foldid, type.measure, grouped, keep))
##     cvm = cvstuff$cvm
##     cvsd = cvstuff$cvsd
##     cvname = cvstuff$name
##     out = list(lambda = lambda, cvm = cvm, cvsd = cvsd, cvup = cvm + 
##         cvsd, cvlo = cvm - cvsd, nzero = nz, name = cvname, glmnet.fit = glmnet.object)
##     if (keep) 
##         out = c(out, list(fit.preval = cvstuff$fit.preval, foldid = foldid))
##     lamin = if (type.measure == "auc") 
##         getmin(lambda, -cvm, cvsd)
##     else getmin(lambda, cvm, cvsd)
##     obj = c(out, as.list(lamin))
##     class(obj) = "cv.glmnet"
##     obj
## }
## <environment: namespace:glmnet>
```

Comment: It looks like you'll need to look in one of the functions `glmnet` calls to find out what value of `lambda` is actually used when it's set to `NULL` (which is just a code for "do the default thing").