# Is there a way to ask an R function to list its default parameter values?

Tags: r

The R documentation for the cor.test() function does not say which method will be used by default if I do not specify a method.

This brings up the more general question: is there a way to ask a function to list its default parameter values?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803263/is-it-possible-to-query-an-r-function-for-the-default-value-of-its-parameters/19805841#19805841

Comment: When you see a default argument like this: `alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater")`, where the character strings represent the various methods that are available, the first one (here `"two-sided"`) is the default method.